# How to convert array into strings in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have a query that returns a row from database.

I would like to convert resulting array to strings, where each string is named as the dabase header, so I can use those strings in code.

I am currently doing it like below, but that doesn't seem like a good practice (or?)?

```
foreach($news_array as $position_in_main_array => $inner_array_member)
{           
    echo $inner_array_member["Date"];
    echo $inner_array_member["Published"];
    echo $inner_array_member["Title"];
    echo $inner_array_member["Text"];
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use variables as: $mydate = $inner_array_member["Date"]; $mymember = $inner_array_member["Published"]; ?

Comment: That looks just fine to me...!?

Comment: Do you want any separator between string ?

Comment: Simple concatenate array and form a string  eg : str = array1 + array2 ....

Comment: You should use foreach($news_array as $position_in_main_array){foreach($position_in_main_array =>$inner_array_member){echo $inner_array_member['Date'];}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use implode function

```
$headarray = array($inner_array_member["Date"],$inner_array_member["Published"],$inner_array_member["Title"],$inner_array_member["Text"]);

echo implode(" ",$headarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

complete code

```
foreach($news_array as $position_in_main_array => $inner_array_member)
{           
    $headarray[] = $inner_array_member["Date"];
    $headarray[] = $inner_array_member["Published"];
    $headarray[] = $inner_array_member["Title"];
    $headarray[] = $inner_array_member["Text"];
}

echo implode(" ",$headarray);
```

Thanks
Amit

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($news_array as $position_in_main_array => $inner_array_member)
{           
    foreach($inner_array_member as $key =>  $value)
    {           
        echo $key.": ".$value." ";
    }
    //new line echo "\n";
    echo "<br>";
}
```